# WHERE NOT IN Condition and nested query in Ignited Datatable

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm using [Ignited Datatables](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/) for codeigniter 
In my controller i've something like:

```
     $this->datatables
    ->select("customer, sale_status, return_id")
    ->join('warehouses', 'warehouses.id=sales.warehouse_id', 'left')
    ->from('sales')
    ->where('warehouse_id', $warehouse_id);
```

which is quit fine. But now have following query to run

```
    "SELECT * from sales where now() > return_date and id NOT IN (SELECT 
    sale_Id FROM sales where sale_id IS NOT NULL)"
```

that i don't know how to say it in ignited way since i did not find any "WHERE NOT IN" and nested raw query syntax in their documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated and i'm sorry for my poor English.

Comment: i think you've to add it by yourself to this library

Comment: Yeah, I did that, bt still i need help for nested query. sorry for the first part that actually solved after posting the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the correct way in codeigniter would be

```
$strSubQuery = $this->db->select('sale_Id')->from('sales')->where('sale_id IS NOT NULL', NULL, false)->get_compiled_select();

echo $this->db
        ->select('*')
        ->from('sales')
        ->where('return_date <= ', 'now()', false)
        ->where_not_in('id', $strSubQuery, false)
        ->get_compiled_select();
```

basically it means you've to add a `where_not_in` function to your `Ignited Datatables`Library

I don't how you did that but an example could be

```
public function where_not_in($key_condition, $val = NULL, $blnEscape = true)
{
    $this->ci->db->where_in($key_condition, $val, $blnEscape);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nirob110/b0f5f3901ff28c734d75f139e3884dc9
this is how i did that. and i'm getting error undefined method Datatables::get_compiled_select()
i'm sorry, but i couldn't get where i'm doing wrong, but this get_compiled_select method doesn't seem to be exist in ignited datatables class

Comment: `get_compiled_select` is a query builder method and returns the generated query  as a string - you've to build the first query in my answer with the query builder and this string should be used with your `where_not_in` function - meaning `$this->datatables->where_not_in($strSubQuery, NULL, false)->...`

Comment: Yes it worked. I removed get_compiled_select method from last clause of $this->datatables-> ... thanks @sintakonte

Answer (score 0):

from the documents:

```
$this->db->where_not_in()
```

> Generates a WHERE field NOT IN (‘item’, ‘item’) SQL query joined with
>   AND if appropriate

see [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

so in your case, you can try this:

```
$now=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

... 

->select("*")
->from('sales')
->where('return_date <=', $now)
->where_not_in('id',"(SELECT sale_Id FROM sales where sale_id IS NOT NULL)")
```

Comment: not much of a help, neither of them did work as expected. while I solved now() with $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); but couldn't get sql query in where not in clause working yet. thanks for your reply.